# Web IDE for stackoverflow

Tags: feature-request, status-declined

I felt having integrated IDE with SO would be so nice. It would be really helpful to quickly verify the answers with out opening eclipse or other IDE.

Have SO engineers thought as a feature in coming upgrades?

**EDIT**

Most of the time I felt having in-built java editor when trying to answer questions. Agreed there other online tools available, my only thought was having in house.  I knew that is not any easy task.

Comment: This would be a massive project, and these things already exist. Why re-invent the wheel?

Comment: Since you are new to meta, let me answer the "why am I getting downvotes" question that is probably in your mind... Voting works different on Meta in that users often express agreement or disagreement with proposals by voting, in addition to the normal reasons for voting.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by this integration? A side bar to search Stack Overflow? A question & answer bookmarking tool? A way to transfer code from the IDE to Stack Overflow?

Comment: Not a bad start ;( with lot of downvotes,

Answer (score 6):

As Mansfield already mentioned in comments, this would be a **massive undertaking** and there are already plenty of other websites to vett your code against without opening a dedicated IDE.

As examples:

- [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/).
- [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).
- [Compilr](https://compilr.com/cravecode/test-share/main.cs).
- [CodeRun](http://www.coderun.com/ide/).
- [.NET Fiddle](http://dotnetfiddle.net/). (Thanks for this one Robert, I had forgotten!)

All of these can be used to test your code before posting to SO and without having to open an IDE like VS or Eclipse.

Comment: http://dotnetfiddle.net/ too

Comment: ideone.com as well. lots of languages to choose from.